# What is the best way to set geolocalised variables?

Tags: query

I have a site that was happily outputting variables based upon a user's IP address. I was using code that looked to see if a cookie for a user's region was already set and if not, looking up the user's country and then setting said cookie and the appropriate variables.

My code was in a PHP enabled template parsing on output and included the following…

```
$sql = 'SELECT country FROM exp_ip2nation WHERE ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") 
ORDER BY ip DESC LIMIT 0,1';  
list($country) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));
```

But since updating the site in question I find that EE now uses **maxmind.com** data instead of **ip2nation.com**, and that what was a single **ip** field is now 2: **ip_range_low** and **ip_range_high**. As a consequence my code no longer works.

Can anyone suggest how to fix my code or suggest a better way of achieving the same end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just about to have a crack at a little plugin for this but it looks as though Andrew Weaver [beat me to it](https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_country/src). By the sound of it his plugin will do what you're after:

> `{exp:ajw_country}` to display the 2 letter country code of the current IP

Comment: Thanks Dom. Looks promising. Will have a play with it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Just tried ajw_country and it's not working for me. I infer it's because of the change to the data structure as mentioned above. I've commented as such on Andrew's Bitbucket commit: https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_country/commits/e56469a15c7d

Comment: The addon is definitely designed to use the newer data structure as it references the Ip_to_nation_data class. It looks as though Andrew's helping you out so hopefully you'll be able to get it working.